# Using the LSTM layer in encoder in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, autoencoder

I want to build an autoencoder with LSTM layers. But, at the first step of the encoder, I got an error. Could you please help me with that?
Here is the model which I tried to build:

```
import numpy 
import torch.nn as nn

r_input    = torch.nn.LSTM(1, 1, 28) 
activation  = nn.functional.relu
mu_r      = nn.Linear(22, 6)
log_var_r = nn.Linear(22, 6)

y = np.random.rand(1, 1, 28)
def encode_r(y):
    y         = torch.reshape(y, (-1, 1, 28)) # torch.Size([batch_size, 1, 28])
    hidden    = torch.flatten(activation(r_input(y)), start_dim = 1)       
    z_mu      = mu_r(hidden)
    z_log_var = log_var_r(hidden)
    return z_mu, z_log_var
```

But I got this error in my code:

```
RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 1, got 28.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating the layer in the correct way.
[torch.nn.LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) requires `input_size` as the first argument, but your tensor has a dimension of 28. It seems that you want the encoder to output a tensor with a dimension of 22. You're also passing the batch as the first dimension, so you need to include `batch_first=True` as an argument.

```
r_input = torch.nn.LSTM(28, 22, batch_first=True)
```

This should work for your specific setup. You should also note that LSTM returns 2 items, the first one is the one you want to use.

```
hidden = torch.flatten(activation(r_input(y)[0]), start_dim=1)
```

Please read the declaration on the official wiki for more information.

Comment: Thanks . Your answer help me a lot. Actually, I am just moved from tensorflow to torch. It seems that all the details are different.

Comment: Yes, a lot of stuff changes here and there, but as soon as you get used to it you'll be fine!